# Date criteria in sql query, in R

Tags: sql, r

I'm having a problem refining an SQL query within R. I'm querying an Microsoft Access database. I'm not sure if this is an SQL problem or an R problem. I use RODBC to establish a connection, then I'm trying to limit a query by just getting results from 2000-1-1 onward.

When I query the entire field, I used str() to determine the exact date type so I could create a comparison variable. So, I got something like

```
wholeqry <- sqlQuery(channel, 
               paste("select DATE, OTHERFIELD from DB", sep=""))
(testdate <- wholeqry[1,1])
str(testdate)
```

This returns:

```
"1984-11-29 EST"
POSIXct[1:1], format: "1984-11-29"
```

Ok, so I format a variable so I can compare it to this:

```
start <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2000-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"), tz = "EST")
```

Then I check to see if they are indeed comparable with logic operators:

```
testdate < start
start < testdate
```

The results, as expected:

```
TRUE
FALSE
```

Ok, now I feel like I'm ready to do my query. I use paste() to pass start as a variable in the sql statement:

```
qry <- sqlQuery(channel, 
               paste("select DATE, OTHERFIELD from DB where DATE >=", start, sep=""))
```

But, when I check qry, it's the whole field minus two entries. The really confusing part to me is if I check the same entry in my new qry, I get the same date, and can compare it to my start variable, and still get the correct logic results. That is:

```
(testdate <- qry[1,1])
testdate < start
start < testdate
```

Gives the results:

```
"1984-11-29 EST"
TRUE
FALSE
```

So, while two records were kicked out by the comparison, the rest weren't, even though if I manually compare them, they should be rejected. I considered that the format of the date field may not be uniform, as some entries have time zone EDT as opposed to EST, but if I check those entries against my start date, I still get the correct logic results.

Comment: SQL (MSSQL and MySQL at least) wants to have single quote marks around the date. Try that. the sign i mean is -> '

Comment: I tried and got this error message: [1] "22018 -3030 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression."                
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select ACDATE, OTHERFIELD from DB where DATE >='2000-01-01''"

Comment: Ok, since you do some formatting of the date field, try to not do that. SQL is usually quite good att taking care of dates with out human intervention. Is there a date() kind of command in R? If so try to write a query like: `"select DATE, OTHERFIELD from TABLE where DATE>='" & date() & "'"`

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and solved it the following way.  Access requires dates to be surrounded by the '#' symbol.  The following query should work:

```
qry <- sqlQuery(channel, "select DATE, OTHERFIELD from DB where DATE >= #2000-01-01#")
```